# How to solve problems with leftover borders when combining multiple counties?

Tags: qgis

I have a problem with the borders of counties. I  have a shp file with counties and I want to combine them into one large district. Unfortunately, after I chose 'connect the selected objects' one object is not combine with rest. But when I select the object, QGIS 'sees it' as a single object. Has anyone had a similar problem or know how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Edit:

@Joseph - I did it. But still I have this same problem. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of methods:

---

1. Select your counties again and then select from the menubar:

   ```
   Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve
   ```

   and check the *Use only selected features*.

---

2. Click the **Edit** button on your shapefile, selected your features and then from the menubar:

   ```
   Edit > Merge Selected Features
   ```

---

If you still receive errors then you may want to consider running `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check geometry validity` to see if there are errors in your shapefile.

---

**EDIT**:

I believe what you're left with, after you have connected your features, is a *dangle*. This can be removed by running **v.clean** with the `rmdangle` tool with a threshold of `0.1` (default value):

[image: Cleaned]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but the problem occurs all the time.

Comment: @KarolinaC - Does your shapefile contain geometric errors?

Comment: No, I checked it.

Comment: @KarolinaC - I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

I think ,since the solution proposed by Joseph didn't work, your problem is probably because of the type of geometry you are using.

Check if your geometry type is multipolygon then change it to polygon this way your processing will work